# Kubernetes ingress: How to enable HTTPS to backend service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

A typical ingress with TLS configuration is like below:

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: no-rules-map
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: testsecret
  backend:
    serviceName: s1
    servicePort: 80`

By default, the load balancer will talk to backend service in HTTP. Can I configure Ingress so that the communication between load balancer and the backend service is also HTTPS?

Update:

Found [GLBC](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md) talking about enabling HTTPS backend for GCE Ingress. Excerpt from the document:

"Backend HTTPS

For encrypted communication between the load balancer and your Kubernetes service, you need to decorate the service's port as expecting HTTPS. There's an alpha Service annotation for specifying the expected protocol per service port. Upon seeing the protocol as HTTPS, the ingress controller will assemble a GCP L7 load balancer with an HTTPS backend-service with a HTTPS health check."

It is not clear if the load balancer accepts 3rd party signed server certificate, self-signed, or both. How CA cert should be configured on load balancer to do backend server authentication. Or it will bypass authentication check.

Answer (score 6):

On [`ingress-nginx`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) you can use the [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)  annotation and point it to the HTTPS port on the service.

This is ingress controller specific and other ingress controllers might not provide the option (or provide an option that works differently)

With this setup, the ingress controller decrypts the traffic. (This allows the ingress controller to control things like ciphers and the certificate presented to the user and do path-based routing, which SSL passthrough does not allow)

It is possible to configure certificate validation with serveral other (`ingress-nginx`-specific) annotations:
[Docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-certificate-authentication)

- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify (it defaults to "off")
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify-depth
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-ciphers (ciphers, not validation related)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name (Override the name that the cert is checked against)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-protocols (SSL / TLS versions)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-server-name (SNI passthrough)

Comment: Thanks so much. In my case nothing else would work (especially passthrough).

Comment: Nginx ingress can be configured with an HTTPS backend indeed. 
Do we understand correctly, that the Istio ingress https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/
does NOT support the same?

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov It might, but the annotations would differ... (I'm much less familiar with it) (The standard ingress resource does not provide a way to specify it, so it is ingress controller specific) (With istio typically adding TLS, I'm not sure)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg unfortunately it does not:
https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-kubernetes-ingress-not-gateway-to-https-backend-service/12765
A single HTTPS service endpoint can be directly exposed via a L4 LoadBalancer service though (not need in Ingress).

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions in "Backend HTTPS" section of [GLBC](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md), 
GCP HTTP(S) load balancer will build a HTTPS connection with the backend, traffic will be encrypted. There is no need to configure CA certificate on LB side (Actually you can't). This implies the load balancer will skip server certificate authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable SSL-Passthrough config for the ingress or load balancer.
I suggest you using nginx ingress and kube-lego for SSL.

with this combination, you can use the ssl-passthrough config.

[Nginx ingress for k8s](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/)

[kube-lego for generating SSL certificate on the fly](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego)

[Guidance for enable ssl-passthrough config](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/tls.md#ssl-passthrough)

Comment: We want to leverage cloud provider (GCP here) load balancer. Do you know if GCP LB supports SSL-passthrough?

Comment: I don't think The GCP has SSL-passthrough capability.

Comment: SSL Passthrough is different from HTTPS to the backend - it does not allow the ingress controller to control the cert presented externally...